# What's "this" inside a promise creation?

Tags: javascript, promise, fs

There's a github package called [pngjs-draw](https://github.com/aloisdeniel/node-pngjs-draw) that draws primitives onto a png.  Just what I need, but I'd like it to run alongside other async code that uses promises.  I'm attempting to do that, running into something I don't understand about "this".  The pngjs-draw example code from github looks like this...

```
var fs = require('fs');
var drawing = require('pngjs-draw');
var png = drawing(require('pngjs').PNG);

fs.createReadStream("blue.png")
  .pipe(new png({ filterType: 4 }))
  .on('parsed', function() {
    // Draws a pixel with transparent green
    this.drawPixel(150,200, this.colors.black())
    // more examples snipped
    // Writes file
    this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream('blue.out.png'));
  });
```

It uses "this" inside the 'parsed' function, and `this` seems to be an instance of something that has all of the drawing methods.

I'd like to make a more generic version, except return a promise, handle errors, and so on.  But it seems I can't use "this" in the same way when creating the promise.  Here's my attempt...

```
function drawOnPNG(fileIn, fileOut, drawFunction) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      fs.createReadStream(fileIn).pipe(new png({ filterType: 4 })).on('parsed', () => {
          drawFunction(this);  // <--MY PROBLEM, I THINK
          this.pack().pipe(fs.createWriteStream(fileOut)).on('finish', () => resolve()).on('error', error => reject(error));
      }).on('error', error => reject(error));        
  });
}
```

I thought it would be handy to make drawing functions like this...

```
function someDrawFunction(pngThing) {
    pngThing.drawPixel(150,200, this.colors.black());
}
```

Then I could draw like this...

```
drawOnPNG('fileIn.png', 'fileOut.png', someDrawFunction).then(...
```

But, when this executes, pngThing isn't what I hoped.  Inspecting it with the debugger, it's a very big object with seemingly all the JS classes defined on it.  Can you suggest a way to access the drawing object inside the promise creation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with the promise constructor, and everything to do with the change from `.on('parsed', function() {` to `.on('parsed', () => {`

Comment: Thanks @Bergi.  The duplicate helped me understand that I misdiagnosed the error to be about promises, rather than arrow functions. Is the SO rule that different questions which have the *same answer* are dups?  Seems like there's a some stigma attached to having one's question marked as dup (not doing one's homework, and so on), but I don't think I would have found that dup through research, given my basic misunderstanding. Anyway, very glad to have gotten the help figuring it out.  Thanks again.

Comment: There is no intentional stigma around a question being closed. Being closed as a dupe is just used to quickly link you and anyone else who might come across this to an answer. Being closed as a dupe doesn't indicate that the other question is better, just that your answer is already there; sometimes the question that gets closed is better written, but the other one already has answers. In this case the premise was based on a misunderstanding of where the error came from, so just closing as a dupe would probably not be enough, but closing and leaving a comment as Bergi did is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem has nothing to do with switching to use a Promise. It's that you switched from a regular function to an arrow function for the callback to the 'parsed' event. Arrow functions do not have their own `this`. The fix is to switch `() =>` back to `function () {` and add the corresponding `}` back in.

Answer (score 2):

`.on()` is calling its callback with some specific `this` (probably the png object).

Using an arrow function inherits `this` from its lexical scope, not the callsite, so you ignore that `this`.

You should use a normal `function() {}` expression so you pick up the `this` passed from the callsite.

Comment: Thanks.  Wish I could mark them both correct.